# Should I use geometry type over geography type when usually expecting back a lot of rows?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am in the planning stages of a service that will do a fair share of searches for items in a geographical database.

I will have to use PostgreSQL and PostGIS for that purpose and have learned so far from [this article](https://medium.com/coord/postgis-performance-showdown-geometry-vs-geography-ec99967da4f0) that geography searches returning a lot of rows come with a high performance penalty.

My service will be based around searches asking for every item within a radius from 1km up to 50km.
So I will have to utilize the [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) function a lot.

I am expecting to get back several hundred rows per square km in urban areas but in rural areas probably only a handful.
[edit: added after discussion in the comments]

This made me think so far I might be better of building everything right away in geometry types, until I read in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/63987/131469) to a question about `ST_DWithin()` that the `use_spheroid parameter=false` was added to lower some performance issues. But I could not find out if this would be enough to decide to use geography.

Comment: How big an area does your data cover? if it is not world wide then a local projection would probably be faster and easier to manage

Comment: thanks for the reply! It is planned to cover worldwide data although the single queries would always be localised within 1km - max 50km radius.

Comment: You will find that, to be able to query data worldwide within a *metric* proximity, you are **bound** to spherical/spheroidal computations, or else dive into the abyss of managing projections on a world wide data set - either by logically/spatially separating your data, or with a plethora of (costly) intermediate steps inside your queries (which, ironically, will likely involve casts and/or function calls to then do spherical/spheroidal calculations). The only alternative is a World Mercator projection, which really is useless for distance related analytics due to its distortion.

Comment: Personally, I would need *a lot* more information about your use case to decide *against* `GEOGRAPHY`...

Comment: thank you. i will include the info from my first response and some extra infos about the expected number of rows returning (in urban areas several hundred per sqaure km / in rural areas probably only a handful). 

so far it sounds to me like starting out with `GEOGRAPHY` and later if needed mirroring or converting the data as `GEOMETRY`with local projections.